# Build error for StyleCop.dll

Tags: win-universal-app, prism, prism-6

I am trying to run the Prism sample project [AdventureWorks.Shopper](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Windows/tree/master/AdventureWorks.Shopper)

Problem is, when I build the project, I get the following build error :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The "StyleCopTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly
>   C:\Users\yeasin.nuget\packages\StyleCop.MSBuild\4.7.49.1\build..\tools\StyleCop.dll.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v3.5,
>   Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly
>   and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
>   public class that implements
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.  AdventureWorks.UILogic

Has anyone experience it?

I am using VS 2015 Community with Update 2

Answer (score 2):

I experienced it and it was resolved after installing .NET Framework 2.0 and 3.5 on my machine.

Steef-Jan